# How to change canvas' size in unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, canvas

I can not change canvas' size when it's in Screen Space - Overlay Mode; After some research I found that the size of a canvas is determined by your game's screen size. The canvas just covers your screen. So I think I could change my camera's size to change canvas' size. But it does not work. Does anyone know how to set a specific size to a canvas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So may be my question should be how to change the screen size showed
>   in editor?

To change the screen size, go to the Game window (accessed by the menu "Window->General->Game").  At the top of the window will be a screen size menu (outlined in green, below) to change the screen size.  When pressed, it will display the list of screen sizes that will be emulated.  I say "emulated" instead of "displayed" because it is possible to have a screen size larger than the screen on which you are working.  It is also possible to zoom into a screen.  The "Scale" slider (to the right of the screen size menu) will allow you to scale up/down.

[image]

As a note, the list of screens and resolutions shown are related to the current build target (accessed by "File->Build Settings...").  For example, common iOS screen sizes are displayed in the list when the build target is iOS.

Comment: Thank you so much. You cleared all my confusions even including those I did not asked.

Comment: Happy to help!  An additional note: For my own convenience, I have added Android sizes to the iOS list and visa-versa.  I did this so I don't have to change the "build target" in order to see resolutions of other platforms.  You can do this by clicking the "+" at the bottom of the menu.

Comment: Yeah, this is very convenient:)

Answer (score 2):

Use the Canvas Scaler Component

[image]

[Unity3D Documentation: Canvas Scaler](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-CanvasScaler.html)

Comment: Thank you. By configuring as above, I got the result very close to what I expect. But not 100% perfect. Because this approach scales the canvas to be exactly the same as the screen size only when both of them have the same aspect ratio. So may be my question should be how to change the screen size showed in editor?

Comment: No problem. Have you tried setting the match value to .5?

Comment: Yeah, I tried. I just did not set my screen to my expected size(1920*1080). Its fixed by Topher's answer down below.